# Java7 System.identityHashCode performance

Tags: performance, java-7, hashcode, xstream

The scene:

- I am using XStream, which uses System.identityHashCode a lot.
- I have migrated from IBM Java 1.5 to Oracle Java 7

The problem:

I see a performance problem, and have identified that System.identityHashCode could be my problem.

Questions:

- Is there any good explanation why I am seeing this degradation in performance with the newer Java (and change from IBM to Oracle)?
- How do I get around this bottleneck?

Below are my benchmarks (all run on the same hardware):

```
32 bit Oracle Java 7

System.identityHashCode: 517669471 - 51ns
Object.hashCode: 491220730 - 49ns

64 bit Oracle Java 7:

System.identityHashCode: 353134647 - 35ns
Object.hashCode: 339331774 - 33ns

IBM Java 1.5

System.identityHashCode: 19241979 - 1ns
Object.hashCode: 89621026 - 8ns
```

The source of the bechmark program is:

```
import java.util.*;

public class HashCodeTest
{
  static int ITS = 10000000;
  static Object O = new Object();

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    TreeSet<Integer> large = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    Random ran = new Random();
    for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
      large.add(ran.nextInt());
    }

    testIdentityHashCode(large);
    testHashCode(large);
    testIdentityHashCode(large);
    testHashCode(large);
  }

  protected static void testIdentityHashCode(TreeSet<Integer> large)
  {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i=0; i<ITS; i++) {
      Object o = new Container(large);
      System.identityHashCode(o);
    }
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("System.identityHashCode: " + (end-start) + " - " + (end-start)/ITS + "ns");
  }

  protected static void testHashCode(TreeSet<Integer> large)
  {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i=0; i<ITS; i++) {
      Object o = new Container(large);
      o.hashCode();
    }
    long end = System.nanoTime();

    System.out.println("Object.hashCode: " + (end-start) + " - " + (end-start)/ITS + "ns");
  }

  private static class Container {
    private final Object o;

    public Container(Object o)
    {
      this.o = o;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing this difference probably because System.identityHashCode take's some time to be intrinsified and/or Object.hashCode to be inlined in your method. Plus, you are actually measuring allocation time since you instantiate an object at every step of the loop.

Try this:

```
public class HCTests {

static int ITS = 1000;

@Test
public void run() {

    Object[] o = newArray(1000);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        timeHash(o);
    }

    System.out.println("----------------");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        timeHash(newArray(1000));
    }

}

private Object[] newArray(int max) {
    Object[] o = new Object[max];

    for (int i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
        o[i] = new Object();
    }

    return o;
}

private void timeHash(Object[] o) {
    //store the hashes to avoid possible dead-code elimination
    int[] hashes=new int[o.length];
    long start = System.nanoTime();

    for (int j = 0; j < ITS; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
            hashes[i]=System.identityHashCode(o);
        }
    }

    long elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;

    System.out.println("Elapsed " + elapsed + "(ns). Avg: " + (float)elapsed
            / (o.length * ITS));

    for (int i : hashes) {
        if(i==0) {
            System.out.println("Ooops, got 0 hashCode!!!");
        }
    }
}}
```

For output of the first loop I got (Old Intel Core 2 Duo 2.1GHz)

**Elapsed 7557271(ns). Avg: 7.557271

Elapsed 18508470(ns). Avg: 18.50847**
...
**Elapsed 2026678(ns). Avg: 2.026678**

On the second loop I got

Elapsed 2142041(ns). Avg: 2.142041
Elapsed 1951888(ns). Avg: 1.951888
Elapsed 1929891(ns). Avg: 1.929891
Elapsed 1934779(ns). Avg: 1.934779
Elapsed 1993438(ns). Avg: 1.993438
Elapsed 2133732(ns). Avg: 2.133732
Elapsed 1995882(ns). Avg: 1.995882
Elapsed 2326329(ns). Avg: 2.326329
Elapsed 1939178(ns). Avg: 1.939178
Elapsed 2275980(ns). Avg: 2.275981